# Getting Run-time error '91' Object Variable + Overall Code health

Tags: vba, excel

I've read many threads about the same error I'm having, some of which say you have to declare the worksheet or active sheet. I tried that but didn't work.
I'm getting **"Run-time error '91' Object variable not set"** error.

Here is my code (which I know is poorly written and a mess, apologies for that) I'd appreciate any enhancements also to the code.

```
Option Explicit
Sub BBBB()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim batStartRow As Integer
    Dim batEndRow As Integer
    Dim StartRangeCell As Variant
    Dim StartRange As Range
    Dim vVal
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim FirstDate As Variant

    For i = 0 To Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Range("E:E"))

        Set wb = ThisWorkbook
        Sheet5.Select

        With Sheets("10mins")

            batStartRow = .Range("E:E").Find(What:=i, after:=.Range("E1"), MatchCase:=True, LookAt:=xlWhole).Row
            batEndRow = .Range("E:E").Find(What:=i, after:=.Range("E1"), searchdirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=True, LookAt:=xlWhole).Row
            Set StartRange = Range("E" & batStartRow & " :E" & batEndRow).Offset(0, -3)

            For Each StartRangeCell In StartRange.Cells
                vVal = "100"

                If (WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("B" & batStartRow & ":B" & StartRangeCell.Row), vVal) = 1) Then
                    StartRangeCell.Offset(0, 17) = "y"
                    Set FirstDate = StartRangeCell.Offset(0, -1)
                    Range("S" & batStartRow) = "y"
                Else

                End If
            Next

        End With
    Next

End Sub
```

**Data:**

```
Time            AA  BB  CC
1/27/2018 12:38 0   7   
1/27/2018 12:48 24  7   
1/27/2018 12:58 62  8   y
1/27/2018 13:08 100 8   y
1/27/2018 13:18 100 8   
1/27/2018 13:28 100 8   
1/27/2018 13:38 100 8   
1/27/2018 13:48 100 8   
1/27/2018 13:58 100 8   
1/27/2018 14:08 11  8   
1/27/2018 14:18 3   8   
1/27/2018 14:28 1   8   
1/27/2018 14:38 0   8   
1/27/2018 14:48 0   8   
1/27/2018 14:58 0   8   
1/27/2018 15:08 0   8   
1/27/2018 15:18 0   8   
1/27/2018 15:28 0   8   
1/27/2018 15:38 0   8   
1/27/2018 15:48 0   8   
1/27/2018 15:58 0   8   
1/27/2018 16:08 0   8   
1/27/2018 16:18 0   8   
1/27/2018 16:28 0   8   
1/27/2018 16:38 0   8   
1/27/2018 16:48 0   8   
1/27/2018 16:58 0   8   
1/27/2018 17:08 0   8   
1/27/2018 17:18 0   8   
1/27/2018 17:28 0   8   
1/27/2018 17:38 0   8   
1/27/2018 17:48 25  8   
1/27/2018 17:58 52  9   y
1/27/2018 18:08 100 9   y
1/27/2018 18:18 100 9   
1/27/2018 18:28 100 9
```

**Goal of the code:**
For each set in Column "BB", I would like to have a "y" in Column "CC" corresponding to the first time that the number "100" appears in Column "AA".

The next step is to calculate the time required for it to reach "100".

Any help is appreciated. Thank you again!

Comment: Would be pleasant to see indentations in your code...

Comment: What line of code creates the error?

Comment: @Davesexcel, when I run the code and press Debug, the highlighted line starts with "batStartRow = "

Comment: You need tests for whether anything was found after you used Range.Find e.g. If Not batStartRow  Is Nothing Then....

Comment: Error 91 means you either forgot a `Set` keyword, or you're making an assumption you shouldn't be making, and end up making a member call against an object reference that's actually `Nothing` (i.e. a null reference). In this case `Range.Find` didn't find what it was looking for and returned `Nothing` and your code assumed that couldn't ever happen and that calling `.Row` on the result would always be harmless. Bites every single one of us.. once ;-)

Comment: You'll also run into error 6 "Overflow", should `Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Range("E:E"))` ever return a value greater than 32,767. Declare `i As Long` to avoid this.

Comment: If you want feedback on any/all aspects of the code (from indentation and procedure & variable naming to overall efficiency of the algorithm), post your **working** code (it's important - must work as intended) on [codereview.se].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need tests for whether anything was found after you used Range.Find e.g.

First store the results of Range.Find in variables, then test If they were set to something other than Nothing during the Find operation.

Also, change your `Integers` to `Long` to avoid potential overflow.

e.g.

```
Dim batStart As Range, batEnd As Range

Set batStart =  .Range("E:E").Find(What:=i, after:=.Range("E1"), MatchCase:=True, LookAt:=xlWhole)  
Set badEnd  = .Range("E:E").Find(What:=i, after:=.Range("E1"), searchdirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=True, LookAt:=xlWhole)

If Not batStart Is Nothing Then
    batStartRow = batStart.Row
    'Other code.....
End If
```

Same with  `batEnd`.

Place the rest of what you want to do inside that If statement.

---

Here is a way of only preceeding with code if both ranges were set:

```
With Worksheets("10mins")

            Set batStart = .Range("E:E").Find(What:=i, after:=.Range("E1"), MatchCase:=True, LookAt:=xlWhole)
            Set badEnd = .Range("E:E").Find(What:=i, after:=.Range("E1"), searchdirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=True, LookAt:=xlWhole)

            If batStart Is Nothing Or batEnd Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
            batStartRow = batStart.Row
            batEndRow = batEnd.Row
            Set startRange = Range("E" & batStartRow & " :E" & batEndRow).Offset(0, -3)

            For Each startRangeCell In startRange.Cells

            'your code continue....
```

Comment: IOW separate the two concerns of 1) getting the results of a `Range.Find` call and 2) getting the `.Row` of the search result *if there is one*.

Comment: Oops...I should have scrolled to the right! Thanks for the save @MathieuGuindon

Comment: @QHarr, thanks for your input. But I'm getting an error "Compile Error: Variable not defined" at "batStartRow = batStart.Row"

Comment: Yes, I did add them at the beginning of the Sub

Comment: Did you keep you  Dim batStartRow As Long
    Dim batEndRow As Long at the start? Put Option Explicit at the very top of your module and see what else if flagged and make sure each is declared with type.

Comment: @Qharr, sorry I missed that. When you say "Other Code......" 
Starting from this line: 
Set StartRange = Range("E" & batStartRow & " :E" &  atEndRow).Offset(0, -3) ?

Comment: What do you mean? Did you put all the declarations in?

Comment: Yes, I added them and the variable error disappeared. I guess I'm just confused when you said "Other Code....." , which line in my code do I start from? 
Sorry if it's a stupid question

Comment: And are you doing anything with   Sheet5.Select ? You With statement means you are doing everything with Sheets("10mins"). And what sheet is Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Range("E:E")) supposed to work with.

Comment: Ok I figured it :)
It works now, thank you very much for your assistance!